# Renaming files in a particular folder in a drive using Power shell

Tags: powershell

Usually to rename files in a drive, I use the following command line:

#

```
$old = 'Old Text'
$new = 'New Text'
```

#

```
$oldwildcard = "*$old*"

$items  = Get-ChildItem  -Recurse
[array]::Reverse($items)


foreach($item in $items)
{
    if($item.name -clike $oldwildcard)
    {
        Write-Host $item.FullName -ForegroundColor green
        $newName = $item.name -creplace $old, $new 
        Rename-Item -Path $item.PSPath -NewName $newName
    }
}
```

#

Now I only need to rename files in the folder e.g. O:\Reviews. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$items  = Get-ChildItem -path "O:\Reviews"` for only in the folder e.g. O:\Reviews **OR** `$items  = Get-ChildItem -path "O:\Reviews" -Recurse` for the files/folders inside O:\Reviews.

Comment: ok thanks for your prompt reply, I have managed :)

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh post that as the answer so it can be accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) cmdlet in PowerShell has the `-path` parameter, where in it takes the path (as a string) for the location for which you want to list the items and child items.

So in your case, all you need to do it is change `$items = Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to `$items = Get-ChildItem -path "O:\Reviews"`.

So your overall code looks like -

```
$oldwildcard = "*$old*"

$items  = Get-ChildItem -path "O:\Reviews"
[array]::Reverse($items)

foreach($item in $items)
{
    if($item.name -clike $oldwildcard)
    {
        Write-Host $item.FullName -ForegroundColor green
        $newName = $item.name -creplace $old, $new 
        Rename-Item -Path $item.PSPath -NewName $newName
    }
}
```